# Xtext Adding values to the grammar manually

Tags: java, xtext, xtend

I have a grammar that can parse a list of containers and modules, then generate these containers in alphabetical order. But, I also want to add the module names into the container list.

For example:

```
With the configuration:
CONTAINER cont1;
CONTAINER cont2;
MODULE external WITH PRIORITY 1;
MODULE internal WITH PRIORITY 2;


The generated file should have:
main()
{
  Container(cont1);
  Container(cont2);
  Container(external);
  Container(internal);
}
```

I was able to generate what is in the CONTAINER configuration. But I want to merge the module names "internal" and "external" into the container. Then sort them alphabetically.

Is there a way to do this in xtext? And does this belong to the generator or scoping part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should go into the generator. What you need it generate a list of all `CONTAINER` and `MODULE` nodes. I assume that you've written the generator in Xtend:

```
val list = Lists.newArrayList( model.containers )
list.addAll( model.modules )
```

iterate over the sorted list:

```
for( part : list.sortBy(e|e.name) ) {
    part.generateContainer()
}
```

and then one generateContainer() method per type.